# Django DRF PUT Request ImageField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

I am uploading images using the ImageField in Django. After saving the image in the database when I GET the data to display on the frontend, I get it in the format:

```
{"pk":5,"employee_image":"/media/emp_temp_mast/5.png","first_name":"TEST",}
```

After changing the data on the frontend, I send a PUT request for the respective entry in the form:

```
{"pk":5,"employee_image":"/media/emp_temp_mast/5.png","first_name":"DATA CHANGED",}
```

However I get the following error after making the request:

```
employee_image: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

How should I call the PUT request from frontend.

Comment: If you only want to change _part_ of the data that does not include the actual `employee_image` field, then use the `PATCH` method and simply don't include the fields you don't want to update:  `fetch('https://foo.bar/Baz/', { method: 'PATCH', body: '{"pk":5, "first_name": "DATA CHANGED"}')` .

Comment: This is just an example, I need to make a put request in this case. The data needs to be added to a duplicate table and removed from here

Comment: My question is basically what is the most efficient way to carry on a PUT request for a imagefield after you GET the data from the database?

Comment: Nuke the `ImageField` on the sending JSON and use all other fields.  Then do a `PATCH`.  e.g. `let send_data = {...data}; delete send_data['employee_image']; fetch([...]method:'PATCH')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by @Ross Rogers worked but I feel that it can get a little tedious as we expect every client side application to be aware that they have to Nuke the ImageField on every UPDATE request they intend to make. The client side should be able to make this abstraction and should not need to worry about the handling of the ImageField.

To achieve that I made the following change to the view where the backend receives the ImageField.

```
class Emp_DetailView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return db_data
        except Emp_Mast.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        db_data = self.get_object(pk)

        if(db_data["employee_image"] and db_data["employee_image"].startswith('http'))):
            img_name = dataDict["employee_image"].split("/")[-1]
            emp_img_temp = ContentFile(requests.get(dataDict["employee_image"]).content, name=img_name)
            dataDict["employee_image"] = emp_img_temp

        serializer = Emp_Mast_Serializer(db_data, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

A GET request is sent on the image URL and then the result is saved in a file format which can be used to send a PUT request