# Django DRF PUT Request ImageField after GET request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I make a PUT request for an imageField after getting the data from the database.
I receive the data in the form of a URL "/media/img.png"

When I PUT the same data back, I get the error ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]

What is the best way to PUT this data.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Is this answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036805/12261752

Comment: I have asked a similar question explained in a bit more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382308/django-drf-put-request-imagefield. I think the above link does not answer the question as the image being received is not Base64 string, it is the URL django creates and sends in the GET request