# Django DRF Unable to send PUT request with Image Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a form in React through which I am sending some data which includes an ImageField. I am able to perform a POST request and the data is being sent to Django backend successfully. However, when I try to modify the data I get employee_image: `

> ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the
> form."]

This is the data coming up on GET request:

> [
> {
> "id": 2,
> "product_name": "XYZ",
> "product_description": "XYZ",
> "product_price": "12.00",
> "product_unit_weight": "120.00",
> "product_unit_weight_units": "GM",
> "product_type": "CPG",
> "product_image": "http://192.168.29.135:8000/media/product_images/xyz.png"
> },

This is my models.py file:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_name = request.data['product_name']
        product_description = request.data['product_description']
        product_price = request.data['product_price']
        product_unit_weight = request.data['product_unit_weight']
        product_unit_weight_units = request.data['product_unit_weight_units']
        product_type = request.data['product_type']
        product_image = request.data['product_image']
        Product.objects.create(product_name=product_name, product_description=product_description, product_price=product_price, product_unit_weight=product_unit_weight, product_unit_weight_units=product_unit_weight_units, product_type=product_type, product_image=product_image)
        return Response({'message':'Product created successfully'}, status=200)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Put method running')
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        product = get_object_or_404(Product.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        print(product)
        if (product.product_image.startswith('http')):
            img_name = dataDict["product_image"].split("/")[-1]
            product_img_temp = ContentFile(request.get(dataDict["product_image"]).content, name=img_name)
            dataDict['product_img'] = product_img_temp
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried following this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382308/django-drf-put-request-imagefield) and edited my models.py with the update() as shown above. But the error that I get is:

> 'Product' object has no attribute 'data'

Also, When I am printing the product in the update() method, I am getting only the product name printed and not the rest of the fields. I am unable to understand why I am getting this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 0):

Here are several problems you have to overcome.

1. From the client-side(React) you need make FormData to send an image or file.
2. In python every object has some special magic method one of them ar **str**, which method returns the string. When we print an object then this **str** method string was print except for print full object data. if you want to print full data you need to use `print(product.__dict__)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "patch" method to make your request instead of the "put" request. Patch uses partial_update() function therefore, you will need to define a partial_update() function as well.